# How to add a browse and upload field in a form? The items are mp4 files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

There is no column available other that cheesy hyperlink column that makes you add the link. Is there a way to either add a browse to upload ( and confine it to a folder area to select from ) or some sort of dropdown folder that can select from a list ( where they upload the mp4s ) and when they select that matching dropdown link that mp4 can play from that that new list?

SharePoint 2010

[image]

Comment: Why not using attachments for that?

Comment: Because the attachment is for another image.

Comment: You can add multiple attachments, the upload field in the form that you need .. where will you store its content?

Comment: Through infopath perhaps but how do I add 2 attachment fields one for image and one for video ? And is there a way to point them to a folder or area to begin with? Store it in a library perhaps.

Comment: are you using InfoPath for this question?

Comment: Either. I suppose Infopath would be the best solution.

Comment: In any list, you can click on the ribbon in the form "Attach File", then attach anything, the attachment will appear at the end. You can click the button again, and attach another file, and so on..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50583/discussion-between-mohamed-derhalli-and-mike-rooker).

Comment: I updated a snapshot.